# Resizing image before it displays

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to hide an img tag so that I can later display it with jquery once page has fully loaded.

The image loads as a tag:

```
<img id="img1" src="images/4main.jpg" width="600" height="900" >
```

I have css to hide img:

```
 #img1 { display:none; }
```

in my external js file I have

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#img1").css('display', 'block !important');
}
```

This works fine on all browsers except ie7 and ie8.   The image remains hidden.

I need the jquery because I want to resize the file before it displays.

Any ideas as to get it to show on ie7 & ie8?

Comment: Is the CSS above an error, or just a typo? #img shouldn't do anything, it should be #img1

Comment: sorry just a typo here.  it's correct in my files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your jQuery to this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("#img1").show();
}
```

or

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#img1").show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuerys window load function instead by doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#img1").css('display', 'block !important');
});
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help.  IE8 and 7 recognize the window.load event because images are being resized just not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it an id and hiding/showing with jquery's built in helprers

```
$('#myimage').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because IE will cache the image, and the onload event will never fire, because its already loaded "in cache".
On an other note; doing what you are trying to do is NOT recommended, since the user will be downloading the whole file anyway. You should resize it on the serverside!

But to acchieve what you want, just use simple css (no onload/display none magic);

```
img{
    width:100%;
}
```

the img's parent needs to be position:relative and then the image will be automatically as big as its parent.

hope i helped